# What are the privacy implications of using a prescription discount from the manufacturer?

Tags: united-states, privacy, medical, health

Healthcare providers and pharmacies will sometimes offer a manufacturer card or coupon to provide a discounted price for a prescription product.

My understanding is that pharmacies are bound by HIPPA and obligated not to disclose Protected Health Information (PHI). Some prescription discounts are operated by 3rd parties and some manufacturer discounts are apparently via anonymous coupon, but in some cases when the manufacturer provides a discount on a prescription, PHI is supplied to the manufacturer as part of the process.

Is the manufacturer then any less obligated than the pharmacy with regard to privacy, security, marketing uses, disclosures, etc. of the PHI, or is the primary privacy risk simply that one additional party now holds PHI that is vulnerable to loss or abuse?

Comment: I'm not sure this works how you think it does... Manufacturer A gives provider some stack of coupons. When you use it, the provider returns it to the manufacturer for a credit on a future or current bill. No PHI is exchanged...

Comment: Not in this case. It's not just a coupon or a general-purpose discount card. The provider specifically states that PHI is given to the manufacturer as part of getting approved for the discount. Now clarified in the question.